# CryptSignMessage giving wrong size

Tags: java, windows, cryptography, jna, cryptoapi

We're using JNA to access the functions provided by the native library Crypt32.dll.

```
public interface IWinCrypt extends StdCallLibrary {

IWinCrypt WIN_CRYPT_LIB = Native.load("Crypt32", IWinCrypt.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

/**
 * Creates a hash of the specified content, signs the hash, and then encodes both the original message
 * content and the signed hash.
 *
 * @param cryptSignMessagePara structure containing the signature parameters.
 * @param fDetachedSignature   TRUE if this is to be a detached signature. Otherwise, FALSE.
 * @param cToBeSigned          Count of the number of array elements in rgpbToBeSigned and rgpbToBeSigned.
 * @param rgpbToBeSigned       Array of pointers to buffers that contain the contents to be signed.
 * @param rgcbToBeSigned       Array of sizes, in bytes, of the content buffers pointed to in rgpbToBeSigned.
 * @param pbSignedBlob         A pointer to a buffer to receive the encoded signed hash.
 * @param pcbSignedBlob        A pointer to a DWORD specifying the size, in bytes, of the pbSignedBlob buffer.
 * @return true on success else false
 */
boolean CryptSignMessage(WinCryptDataTypeMapping.CryptSignMessagePara.ByReference cryptSignMessagePara,
                         boolean fDetachedSignature,
                         int cToBeSigned,
                         PointerByReference rgpbToBeSigned,
                         IntByReference rgcbToBeSigned,
                         Pointer pbSignedBlob,
                         IntByReference pcbSignedBlob);
```

Similar to the example provided in the documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/example-c-program-signing-a-message-and-verifying-a-message-signature, to find the size required by the signature we first pass a null value in place of the pointer to the signed blob.

```
final Memory ptr = new Memory(message.length);
ptr.write(0, message, 0, message.length);
final PointerByReference aMessage = new PointerByReference(ptr);
final IntByReference pMessageLen = new IntByReference(message.length);
final IntByReference pSignLen = new IntByReference();

IWinCrypt.WIN_CRYPT_LIB.CryptSignMessage(signMessagePara, true, 1, aMessage, pMessageLen, null, pSignLen)
```

And then make a call again after allocating memory of that size for the signed blob,

```
final Memory signature = new Memory(pSignLen.getValue());
IWinCrypt.WIN_CRYPT_LIB.CryptSignMessage(signMessagePara, true, 1, aMessage, pMessageLen, signature, pSignLen)
```

However the second call always fail and the error is `com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Win32Exception: More data is available.` which turns out is due to the sign requiring more space. For a test, I can see that the first call says the size will be 2019 bytes while the second calls fails saying `more data is available` and the new pSignLen value is 2081 bytes.

Few more details,

- os version - Windows Server 2019
- java version - happens on both java 8 and java 11
- JVM Bitness - 64
- JNA Version - tried with different versions 5.0.0 and above

Answer (score 4):

The documentation of the fourth and fifth parameters indicate these are arrays, of `Pointer` and `DWORD` (`int`) respectively:

```cs
  [in]      const BYTE * []          rgpbToBeSigned,
  [in]      DWORD []                 rgcbToBeSigned,
```

You copied the description in the javadoc:

```java
 * @param rgpbToBeSigned       Array of pointers to buffers that contain the contents to be signed.
 * @param rgcbToBeSigned       Array of sizes, in bytes, of the content buffers pointed to in rgpbToBeSigned.
```

but not the mapping:

```java
PointerByReference rgpbToBeSigned,
IntByReference rgcbToBeSigned,
```

While the `PointerByReference` might coincidentally match the allocation of a 1-Pointer array, the `IntByReference` is pointer-sized on your 64-bit system, and represents an `int[2]` which doesn't match.  This mismatch may corrupt the stack.

This function is [already mapped at the JNA project here](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/ca465eea894c72e1da313623c7d6e2f01ac04053/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Crypt32.java#L278).  Including the `jna-platform` dependency should give you access to it:

```java
boolean CryptSignMessage(CRYPT_SIGN_MESSAGE_PARA pSignPara, boolean fDetachedSignature, int cToBeSigned,
    Pointer[] rgpbToBeSigned, int[] rgcbToBeSigned, Pointer pbSignedBlob, IntByReference pcbSignedBlob);
```

The [unit test for this class contains tested code](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/ca465eea894c72e1da313623c7d6e2f01ac04053/contrib/platform/test/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Crypt32Test.java#L191-L293) that works using this mapping.